# Can number of dashes be determined in css border bottom property?

Tags: html, css

I want to have an input textbox with following requirements.

1. With fixed size.
2. Only bottom dashed border with number of dashes equal to the size.

I tried:

```
<div>
    input text: <input size="5" maxlength="5"/>
</div>
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/fs0ygsf1/1/) is the fiddle that I tried.

is it possible to have number of dashes equalto the size attribute of the textbox?

If yes, How can I do it?

Comment: Not possible to handle .... You will need JS to enclose each letter and put the border bottom

Comment: ^ what he said, and it doesn't help either that each browser displays dashed borders differently.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's **not possible**. Every browser renders dashed borders differently.

You could use a workaround. In the following example I have added a `ul` which simulates the number of characters which can be used

```css
input{
    border:none;
    border: 0px dashed;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

input:focus{
    outline:0
}

div{
    border: 2px solid #CCC;
    padding: 50px;
}


ul {
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    right: -30px;
    height: 1px;    
}

li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 2px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    input text: <input size="5" maxlength="5"/>
    <ul><li>_</li><li>_</li><li>_</li><li>_</li><li>_</li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I am finding it hard to access the input box.

Comment: @vinesh You could change the position of the `ul` or set `min-width:100px` on the `input`. Just play with the CSS values. Good luck.